# preg_match and escaping when inside double quotes

Tags: php, escaping, preg-match, newline, double-quotes

Complete PHP newbie here trying to get to grips with literals and escapes, so apologies in advance that this is so basic. I've read lots of questions on `preg_match` but none seem to address this.

I have an old form which contains instances of the deprecated `eregi()` function using double quotes:

```
eregi("\n", $s)
eregi("%0a", $s)
```

Those 2 lines are part of a longer line to check for injection characters.

If I update the function to `preg_match` with delimiters and a trailing `i`, like so:

```
preg_match("/\n/i", $s)
preg_match("/%0a/i", $s)
```

Do I now also need to escape the `\` and/or `%` with my own back slash(es)?

Thanks

Comment: No, no escaping needed. The only time you need to escape is for the normal instance of a quotes inside quotes. Otherwise it's normal RegEx syntax inside the two forward slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running more than one `preg_match()` call, I recommend using pipes `|` to combine all invalid characters into one call.

In your case, **no escaping is needed** and you can use: `preg_match(/\n|%0a/,$s)`

If you wish to add more blacklisted characters, you can test your pattern against your own sample input at https://regex101.com/

Lastly, if you don't necessarily want to block incoming data, but wish to remove blacklisted characters you could use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).